# Nativescript app not reading http/json data

Tags: nativescript

I have this app in the playground:

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=Azbs38&v=3

In the device log I am seeing `SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Expected '}'` but I am not sure why. The [JSON I am calling](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/marklocklear/45b92c42b73619fbdad213863736570f/raw/415dd6efa28a2e28e83c61be506a3cf87956ec8f/items.json) is valid. What might the problem be?

Comment: The Playground seems to be working just fine.

Comment: You are seeing "items" in the list view? I see the action bar label at the top, but the rest of the screen is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the response header content-type being returned is text/plain.

It should be application/json.